# What are some interesting things I can do with Webkit's console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, webkit

Using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` is easier and much less disruptive to debugging.
Most notably, to get around the `[Object object]` errors:

```
console.log("A comment!", myObject)
```

There are a few other basic things that I've been using, like:

```
console.warn("foo")
```

[image: console.warn()]

```
console.error("foo")
```

[image: console.error()]

```
console.count("bar")
```

[image: console.count()]

Then I noticed some really cool things that the <kbd>[d3plus.js](http://d3plus.org/)</kbd> devs did with their console logs, and it got me thinking.

#### What are some other useful things you can do with Webkit's `console._things_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Console API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) is a great reference for this.

Grouping console out put with the group methods is very handy, as well as the profile methods.

I've also started using `console.assert()` from time to time.